# Image within td to be height of the td

Tags: html, css

What I want is the image to be the same height of the `td` when the image isn't there, i.e. 300px, not the height of the image src. I can't specifiy the height of the image, td or table since the parent div represents the height of a responsive container. I've spent far too long on this and tried many things and for some reason the image always insists on being its full height.

```html
<div style='height:300px;width:300px;'>
  <table style='height:100%;width:100%;'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img style='height:100%;width:100%;' src='https://placehold.it/1920x1200'>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use NSFW images in your examples. You seem to have a random `</div>` after the image.

Comment: You want an image to be 100% height when it isn't there, am I missing something?  Surely when the source is missing, the browser will show the alt text or that silly little icon of a missing image (which I don't think you can resize)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Try This, added "overflow: hidden;position: relative;" to parent and "position: absolute;" to child

```
 <div style='height:300px;width:300px;'>
  <table style='height:100%;width:100%; overflow: hidden;position: relative;'>
    <tr>
      <td style='position: absolute;'>
        <img style='height:100%;width:100%;' src='https://placehold.it/1920x1200'>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

output screen

[image]

Comment: This guy knows the score! Thanks!!

Comment: This seems like a very hacky solution to get around the issue.  There are better ways to size an image than to force positioning hacks and cut off anything that flows outside of the bounding box.

Comment: @ChrisBarr  my answer might not be ok for you but it helped "Malooii"

Comment: This solution works in the isolated test case but when I include it in a view in my angular JS app it doesn't work :( - I've tried to see what could be preventing it from working but can't find anything - any advice would be great - thanks - Also I've changed the image to:    <img style='height:100%;' src='https://placehold.it/192x1200'>

Comment: create classes for parent and child elements and add related css into that and use class instead of inline CSS that would work for angular as well

Comment: @Malooii is it working for you now by creating css classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS instead of inline styles.  This helps keep your code more flexible. I've set the `height` and `width` to be `auto` and the `max-height` and `max-width` to be at `100%` so that the image is contained inside the table cell, but also correctly scaled.

```css
.table-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
}

table td img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class='table-container'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src='https://placehold.it/1920x1200' />
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: why there is extra space below image inside td SIR?

Comment: @Bhanupratap fixed now, the image needed to have `display: block;` added to it.  Good catch!

Comment: this doesn't work in the case of a responsively sized container

Comment: please check output it still having extra space below image, i can see when i click on Run code snippet button

Comment: @MalooiiYes that's true, and now I see that in your original question - sorry!  Your code example had a fixed size though

Comment: @Bhanupratap If you are talking about the whitespace between the blue and the red borders, yes that is expected since the container with the red border has a fixed size of 300x300